# "rvm docs generate" is killed

Tags: ruby, rvm, rdoc

Any idea why rvm(1.18.15) fails to generate the document for ruby2.0?

`$ rvm docs generate`

> > ri documentation, be aware that this could take a *long* time, and depends heavily on your system resources...
> >     ( Errors will be logged to /home/user/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/docs.log )
> >     Generating rdoc documentation, be aware that this could take a *long* time, and depends heavily on your system resources...
> >     ( Errors will be logged to /home/user/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/docs.log )
> >     /home/user/.rvm/scripts/docs: line 81:  6696 Killed                  rdoc -a -o "${rvm_docs_path:-"$rvm_path/docs"}/$rvm_docs_ruby_string/$rvm_docs_type" > /dev/null 2>> "${rvm_log_path}/$rvm_docs_ruby_string/docs.log"

Below is the content of the docs.log.

> > uh-oh! RDoc had a problem:
> >     uninitialized constant RDoc::RI::Paths::SITEDIR
> >
> > run with --debug for full backtrace
> >
> > Generating Darkfish format into /home/user/.rvm/docs/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rdoc...
> >     uh-oh! RDoc had a problem:
> >     uninitialized constant RDoc::RI::Paths::SITEDIR
> >
> > run with --debug for full backtrace
> >
> > Generating Darkfish format into /home/user/.rvm/docs/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rdoc...

Comment: Does the referenced `docs.log` tell you more information?

Comment: Did you try to run it with --debug? If so, anything interesting there?

Comment: The --debug option doesn't give any further info than it is run without the option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is `rdoc` / `ruby` issue:

- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8037
- https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/193
- https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/194

you can overcome this problem by reinstalling ruby with `--docs` flag:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --docs
```

Comment: Is it required to upgrade rvm to development head for this rdoc generation issue?

Comment: yes, there is a change for handling of `--docs` flag, it will be going stable in few days, all the code is working good already, we need mostly to improve docs and warning messages before release

Comment: The "killed" issue seems to be fixed, but "ri Array" returns "Nothing known about Array". So I guess rvm fails to generate the ri data.

Comment: does `rvm config-get configure_args` contain `--disable-install-doc` or `--enable-install-doc`?

Comment: are you sure `rvm get head` worked as expected? it should use `--enable-install-doc` instead.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The rvm version is 1.18.21(master) now.

Comment: open a ticket for RVM https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/ - I will help you debug there and ensure it is fixed

Comment: I wish github would use openID in future. But no worry about this issue since I have a workaround `rdoc -r`. I appreciate your help for resolving the "killed" issue.